# sql optimize update and select queries

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I have the same sql script:

```
....

update table_1 set atrDate_1 = date_1
where atr_1 = param_1
and atr_2 <= param_2
and atr_3 > param_3
and ...

select * from table_1
where atr_1 = param_1
and atr_2 <= param_2
and atr_3 > param_3
and ...
....
```

In this script I have two queries. How you can see the conditions in these queries is equals.

My business rules require the implementation of these queries in the order in which I show you. But I think this queries is not optimal, because I need to use equals conditions in the queries.

May be you know how optimize my queries?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create any index?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, I have index in `table_1`. I have index on `atr_1` and `atr_2`

Comment: Is this Advantage Database Server or Microsoft SQL Server? If your question has nothing to do with Microsoft SQL Server then the `tsql` tag is wrong here.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff I use the Advantage Database Server. Sorry, if I used the wrong tag.

Comment: @netwer If you use wrong tags you may get wrong answers, so I suggest you edit your question and remove the wrong tag.

Comment: @JensMühlenhoff Thanks. I removed wrong tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary table which contains the primary key column(s) of your table.

You can then use this temporary table as a filter which might be faster than applying your filter predicates multiple times.

```
SELECT
  id
INTO #ids
FROM table_1
WHERE
      atr_1 =  param_1
  AND atr_2 <= param_2
  AND atr_3 >  param_3
  AND ...

UPDATE
  t1
SET 
  atrDate_1 = date_1
FROM #ids    tmp
JOIN table_1 t1  ON id = tmp.id

SELECT
  t1.*
FROM #ids    tmp
JOIN table_1 t1  ON id = tmp.id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this solution is more helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the second `select` statement instead use `Output` statement in `update`

```
UPDATE table_1
SET    atrDate_1 = date_1
output inserted.*
WHERE  atr_1 = param_1
       AND atr_2 <= param_2
       AND atr_3 > param_3 
       .....
```